# Short form of if behaves differently

Tags: bash, shell

In my unit test part, I've a script `unit_runner.sh` which looks for my unit tests files, sources them and runs every test function in them.

> unit_test_runner script

Please note that my tests are not supposed to write in the *stdout*

```
# ${test} contains the test function name
# So this runs a test, catch the error message if any
error_output=$(${test} 2>&1)
code=$?
# If the executed test does not return 0 or writes into stderr,
# consider it as failure
if [[ ${code} -ne 0 || ! -z ${error_output} ]]
then
     # error
fi
```

> A specific test function
>   In one test function I had:

```
test_do_something() {
    # the function I want to test

    result=do_something ${input}

    if [[ "${result}" = "fake output" ]]
    then
        exit 55
    fi
}
```

This worked and this test passed. I wanted to shorten it as follows

```
 [[ "${result}" = "fake output" ]] && exit 55
```

This makes my test fail. AFAIK, these two forms as exactly the same in terms of behaviors.

What's wrong?

Comment: A non zero exit code returned to the shell will always cause a failure. So its skeptical when you say it passed int the first case. How are you checking the exit code. As such what you have are exactly the same

Comment: How do you check that you test passed ?

Comment: Thank you guys, I updated my question

Comment: @Thomas test is the test function to run as I said in my first sentence

Comment: @smarber: What does your `test` contain? What output does it print i.e. what is stored in `error_output`?

Comment: Very strange .. is ${result} always the same ?

Comment: @Inian I updated my answer. Basically, my unit runner script looks for all test functions to run them dynamically. It puts them in a variable `tests` then iterates over it. Tests should return 0 and should not write in stdout to be considered as success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the exit code of a function is the exit code of the last statement in that function.

The `if` statement has an exit code of 0 if its condition was false:

```
$ if false; then echo false; fi
$ echo $?
0
```

But if we use the short form, the result is the exit code of the entire expression. Because the part before `&&` evaluates to false (i.e. 1), the second part doesn't get executed, and the result of the first part becomes the exit code of the entire expression:

```
$ false && echo false
$ echo $?
1
```

To work around this, you can add an explicit `return 0` or `exit 0` at the end of your function, but this defeats the purpose of the shorthand notation.

---

Reference: the `bash` manpage.

> `[[ expression ]]`
>
> Return a status of 0 or 1 depending on the  evaluation  of
>   the  conditional  expression  expression.
>
> ...
>
> `if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi`
>
> The `if` list is executed.  If its exit status is zero, the `then` list is executed.  Otherwise, each `elif` list is executed in turn, and if its exit status is zero, the corresponding `then` list is executed and the  command
>                 completes.  Otherwise, the `else` list is executed, if present.  The exit status is the exit status of the last command executed, or zero if no condition tested true.

Comment: Thansk!! this is what I should do then `[[ ! "${result}" = "fake output" ]] || exit 55`

Comment: That works (you can use `!=` to make it clearer), but I would personally prefer the `if` form because it doesn't have this pitfall. You can make it shorter by putting it all on one line too, if you prefer.